# Show / hide a tab in primefaces

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I need to show/Hide a tab within a tabView based on selection of a dropdown value.
I have written a javaScript function where in i had to write a logic to show/hide this tab.
I'm not able to get the client id using the id of the tab.
Is there any way to hide /show the tab with javascript without using rendered condition

Code Snippet :

```
    <p:tabView orientation="left" widgetVar="table" id="tabId">
    <p:tab title="Godfather Part I" id="tab1">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
           <h:outputText
                value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone..." />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Godfather Part II" id="tab2">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
           <h:outputText value="Francis Ford Coppola's legendary..." />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Godfather Part III" id="tab3">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
         <h:outputText value="After a break of more than 15 years..." />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a `<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.onChange}">` inside your dropdown menu, and create a method in your bean as follows: (please note that you can also use valueChangeListener with a ValueChangeEvent!)

```
public void onChange(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
  /* get the value from the dropdown into a variable, supposing the dropdown
     contains Integers with possible tab indexes, or contains objects
     with these indexes as attributes.
  */  
  String tabIndex = (String) ((UIOutput)event.getSource()).getValue();
  ...
  RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('table').select(" + tabIndex + ");");
  //in this case, table is the widgetVar of your tabView.
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: OP said: "I need to show/Hide a tab ...".  The suggested solution only selects a specific tab; it does not toggle the tab's visibility.